# actionscript3 custom event in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, custom-event

I want to dispatch a custom event at the end of my movieclip.
I wrote the code on the last frame:

> stop();
>
> import flash.events.Event;
>
> var evt:Event = new
>   Event('finishedWriting', true);
>   this.dispatchEvent(evt);
>
> this.addEventListener("finishedWriting",
>   evtHandler);
>
> function evtHandler(evt:Event):void{
>     trace('finished'); }

but this does not work. 
Any suggestions?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dispatching the event before the listener is set up.